# capture group, artifact, and version for all the jars in the classpath for an Oozie Java action

Tags: java, spring-boot, oozie

I was recently asked to troubleshoot an issue with a Spring Boot program that gets executed by Oozie. Unfortunately, I don't have access to the Spring Boot application or the logs. :) I *do* have the output from `mvn dependency:tree -Ddetail=true`

I'm told that the Spring Boot application runs fine on its own but won't run when executed as an Oozie Java action. We suspect that some of the dependencies that are added to the classpath by Oozie conflict with dependencies from Spring Boot.

This is somewhat speculative, but I'd like to run a simple Oozie Java action that captures the group, artifact, and version for all the dependencies that are added to the classpath and compare that to the dependency tree from the Spring Boot application. I'm thinking that, if there are version conflicts, it might be possible to exclude/resolve them in the pom.xml.

I wrote a class that writes the names of the jars in the classpath to a text file:

```
void captureClasspath(){

    PrintWriter out = null;
    try {
        ClassLoader cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
        URL[] urls = ((URLClassLoader)cl).getURLs();

        out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("/tmp/classpath_capture.txt")), "UTF-8"));

        for (URL url : urls){
            out.println(url.getFile());
        }

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException | FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if(out != null) {
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        }
    }

}
```

The output looks like this:

```
/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/10/mapreduce.tar.gz/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.7.1.2.4.3.0-227-tests.jar
/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/10/mapreduce.tar.gz/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.1.2.4.3.0-227.jar
/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/10/mapreduce.tar.gz/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.7.1.2.4.3.0-227.jar
/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/10/mapreduce.tar.gz/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-2.7.1.2.4.3.0-227.jar
/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/10/mapreduce.tar.gz/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.7.1.2.4.3.0-227.jar
... etc ... (more than 300 lines)
```

Instead of the filename, I'd like to extract the group, artifact and version from these jars. Is that possible? Or is there a better strategy to troubleshoot/resolve this issue given the limited input (no application logs, code, etc...)?

Comment: When Oozie launcher job is launched, it have information about all the jars and being in the class path. Basically what you got using this java action. I believe you have some application specific jars stored into workflow lib directory. You can use one of the property to give preference to your jars. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OOZIE-2066 Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @YoungHobbit. That's a really good suggestion. I'll ask the person who wrote the Spring Boot application to launch it with `oozie.launcher.mapreduce.task.classpath.user.precedence=true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Instead of the filename, I'd like to extract the group, artifact and
>   version from these jars. Is that possible?

This would require reading the contents of each jar file and pulling the group, artifact and version from the relevant entry within the jar file.  Some of the relevant methods for implementing this are [`JarFile#entries()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarFile.html#entries--), [`JarFile#getEntry(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarFile.html#getEntry-java.lang.String-) and [`JarFile#getInputStream(ZipEntry)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarFile.html#getInputStream-java.util.zip.ZipEntry-).

Maven builds will store an entry in the jar at `META-INF/maven/<group>/<artifact>/pom.properties`.  For example, running `jar xf hadoop-common.jar` extracts `META-INF/maven/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-common/pom.properties`, which contains the following data:

```
#Generated by Maven
#Thu Aug 18 01:41:25 UTC 2016
version=2.7.3
groupId=org.apache.hadoop
artifactId=hadoop-common
```

Several common sources of classpath version conflicts for Hadoop applications are Guava, Jackson and Protobuf.

Comment: That was really helpful, @Chris. Thank you. I posted my solution to Github: https://github.com/alexwoolford/classpath-capture

Comment: @AlexWoolford Thank you for sharing that code with the world!